# Transferring for loop from matlab to c++

Tags: c++, matlab, for-loop

I wrote this for loop in matlab:

```
b1=zeros(size(raw));
a1=zeros(size(raw));
filtered = zeros(size(raw));

raw=ones(124,1);
[b,a]=butter(4,6/64,'high');

for n = 5:124

    b1(n)=(b(1)* raw(n))   + (b(2)* raw(n-1) )+ (b(3)* raw(n-2))+ (b(4)* raw(n-3) );
    a1(n)=(b(5)* raw(n-4))-    (a(2)*filtered(n-1)) - (a(3)*filtered(n-2))-(a(4)*filtered(n-3) )- (a(5)*filtered(n-4));

    filtered(n)=b1(n)+a1(n);
end
```

and this in c++

```
for(int i=0;i<124;i++)
{
    temp[i]=1;
}
long double f_temp[124]={0};

long double a[5]={1.0000,-3.2317,3.9766,-2.2014,0.4617};    
long double b[5]={ 0.6795,-2.7178,4.0768,-2.7178,0.6795};

for(int n=4;n<124;n++)
{
    b1=(b[0]*temp[n])+(b[1]*temp[n-1])+(b[2]*temp[n-2]) +(b[3]*temp[n-3]);
    a1=(b[4]*temp[n-4])-(a[1]*f_temp[n-1])-(a[2]*f_temp[n-2])-(a[3]*f_temp[n-3])-(a[4]*f_temp[n-4]);

    f_temp[n]=b1+a1;
}
```

Can anyone explain why they don't give the same answer? The input are the same and the output array is initialized as zero in both cases.

Comment: What are the types of the involved variables (i.e. `b`, `b1`, `temp` etc.)?

Comment: long double. 

long double a[5]={1.0000,-3.2317,3.9766,-2.2014,0.4617}; 
long double b[5]={ 0.6795,-2.7178,4.0768,-2.7178,0.6795};

Comment: You may want to read about [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). I can bet that Matlab has much higher precision than what you will get with `long double` leading to a more precise answer with less rounding errors from Matlab.

Comment: @Alan I think its OK that he uses n < 124, since he starts from n = 4. Matlab has 1 based indexing while C++ has 0 based indexing.

Comment: @user3529587: Please update your question, include example data and complete code (initialisations) which allow to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Unless you use use vpa or similar, matlab uses standard IEEE 64bit float.

Comment: updated. They should have similar answers.. the answer I get is extremely different.

Comment: What's the difference between the two results? My guess is that you are rounding the results you take from butter filter in MatLab only to 4 significant digits in C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong constant values for `a` and `b`, both variables are swapped.

Debugging your m-code:

```
a=[ 0.67945921749947324475016330325161, -2.7178368699978929790006532130064, 4.076755304996839690545584744541, -2.7178368699978929790006532130064, 0.67945921749947324475016330325161]

b=[ 1.0, -3.2316755470122213722561355098151, 3.9766405223795340262427089328412, -2.2013664741369440847051919263322, 0.46166493646287282137663510184211]
```

Comment: I am sorry. I wrote it opposite here, its correct in the actual code.,

Comment: The value of a1 comes correct for both the cases. However the cumulative result comes different